# Why can't add js() to a dropdown field on a form?

Tags: atk4

I just keep getting this error:
Method js is not defined neither in controller, nor in its Model.

Thi is my page

```
class page_alumnos_inscribir extends Page {
function init(){
    parent::init();
    $page=$this;
    $model=$this->add('Model_Alumno')->loadData($_GET['id']);

    $h=$this->add('H3')->set($model->get('name').' ( '.$model->get('grado').$model->get('nivel'). ' )');

    $f=$page->add('Form');
    $r=$f->addField('dropdown','Inscribir al Curso')->setModel('Curso');
    $r->js('change')->univ()->alert('orale');

    $s=$f->addField('line','montoPeriodo');   
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote a wrong chain. Set model returns the added model, you need the created field instead. Try to do it in this way:

```
$r=$f->addField('dropdown','Inscribir al Curso');
$r->setModel('Curso');
$r->js('change')->univ()->alert('orale');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I should also have some other error, the action binded to dropdown does not trigger, It trigers if I bind to the text field, but not the dropdown...weird

Comment: dropdown will not trigger "change" until focus leaves the field, I think. It's a HTML issue.

Comment: It does not trigger not even leaving the field... is there a workaround?

Comment: As a workaround I'm now using autocomplete instead of dropdown

Comment: Well dropdown triggers "change" is it's specified as: $f->getElement('dropfieldname')->js('change', $f->js()->univ()->alert('something'));